# Conditional execution of resources

Tags: chef-infra, conditional-statements, chain

I have the following 2 resources defined within a cookbook that makes HTTP requests. I essentially need to execute `action 2` based on checking a condition from the result of `action 1`. If the condition from `action 1` does not match I need the cookbook to sleep for a period and then try `action 1` again.

What is the best way approach/way to do this ?

```
webhooks_request "Action 1" do
   uri "example.net/data1"
   post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
   expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
   action :post
end
```

I'm using the following `ruby_block` to process the result from `action 1` so I'm thinking it should be possible to then execute `action 2` based on matching the a condition.

```
ruby_block "Parse Response" do
   #Parse the result from action 1
end

webhooks_request "Action 2" do
   uri "example.net/data2"
   post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
   expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
   action :post
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do (warning: this is untested code):

```
node.runstate['my_hook']['retries']=10

webhooks_request "Action 1" do
   uri "example.net/data1"
   post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
   expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
   action :post
   notifies :run, "ruby_block[Parse Response]", :immediately 
end

ruby_block "Parse Response" do
   action :nothing
   block do
     #Parse the result from action 1
     if "result ok from action 1"
       self.notifies :post,"webhooks_request[Action 2]",:immediately
     else
       node.runstate['my_hook']['retries'] -= 1 # decrease to avoid infinite loop
       sleep(10)
       self.notifies :post,"webhooks_request['Action 1']",:immediately
     end
   end
end

webhooks_request "Action 2" do
   uri "example.net/data2"
   post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
   expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
   action :nothing
end
```

Another way would be to do the "Action 1" call inside the ruby block to parse it's output directly.

Something along the line could do (still untested code):

```
ruby_block "try webhook" do
  block do
    r = Chef::Resource::WebhooksRequest.new('Action 1',run_context)
    r.uri "example.net/data2"
    r.post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
    r.expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
    hookretries=10 
    while hookretries do
      r.run_action :post
      # parse data from Action 1
      if "action 1 returned NOK"
         hookretries -= 1
      else 
         break
      end
    end
    hook_retries > 0 # to trigger notify if we're not in timeout
  end
  notifies :post, "webhooks_request[Action 2]", :immediately
end
webhooks_request "Action 2" do
   uri "example.net/data2"
   post_data ({ 'value1' => '1', 'value2' => '2'})
   expected_response_codes [ 200, 201 ]
   action :nothing
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm going to try this.\

Comment: I would add, if you want to skip #2 if #1 times out, then put `not_if { node.runstate['my_hook']['retries'] < 0 }`  (you may have to wrap that in a `lazy` block too.

Comment: @TejayCardon I may be wrong (as I've not tested it) but my last line in block would return true or false, and IIRC (but really unsure) if the ruby_block return false the notification should not be trigerred (I've to test this to confirm this behavior)

Comment: OK, that is officially the coolest idea ever, but looking at the source code, I don't think it is the case.  I've always wanted a clean way to use ruby_blocks without resulting in an always `updated` resource.  Sadly, if I'm right and they don't already behave this way, it would be a hard feature to get added as it would be breaking.  Let me know if you see something different in the code.

Comment: The idea could be  `raise "an exception" unless hook_retries > 0` to fail the entire run if the first webhook never returned something usable after. As it's near sure the rest of the run would have a problem anyway.